# How to bypass for & yield in Scala for a certain function?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have written the following Scala code:

```
  case class A(x: Int, out: List[Int])

  def isIn: Int => List[Int] => Boolean =
    x => l => l.filter { _ == x }.nonEmpty

  def filterTest4: (Int, List[A]) => List[List[Int]] = (x, a) =>
    for (l <- a; if (isIn(x)(l.out))) yield l.out
```

The functrion filterTest4 works perfectly fine, however uses the for & yield, which I do not really like and thus would like to see another way. I would be very happy, if someone offered a constructive comment / answer. Please be nice and keep in mind I just started writing in Scala maybe 3 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the map function, which could be used like this:

```
 def filterTest5: (Int, List[A]) => List[List[Int]] = (x, a) =>
    a.filter { a2 => isIn(x)(a2.out) }.map { a2 => a2.out }
```

I think that does the job.

Comment: correct, every for-yield expression can be replaced by usages of `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`.

Comment: BTW, a more concise version of your solution would be: `a.map(_.out).filter(isIn(x))`

Comment: Just a reminder: `collect` combines `filter` and `map`: `a.collect { case a2 if isIn(x)(a2.out) => a2.out}`

Comment: Yeah it's really better with `collect`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, as other suggested, you can use `collect`, which combines `map` and `filter`. Also you can destructure the case class to access `out` directly.

```
def filterTest5: (Int, List[A]) => List[List[Int]] = (x, a) => a.collect {
  case A(_, out) if isIn(x)(out) => out
}
```